# How to test device reboot using JUnit?

Tags: android

I have created and application that can reboot your device. Now i want to write JUnit for that application. But the problem is when the device is rebooted the JUnit process is also killed.
My test case will pass when the BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast is received.  Please suggest me some ways to test my application. I can go into any depth to resolve this issue.

Comment: but how to mock device reboot

Comment: i have been able to complete this task. I invoked reboot method from my activity and before shutting down i wrote a flag in prefrences. I also registered a BOOT_COMPLETE listener. In onReceive is stared the testCase using am instrumentation command of abd shell.